# NUL: does not work for windows but NULL: does

Tags: java, windows, shell, jboss, null

I encountered the following error when using the JBoss 8 Wildfly Server along with JDK 8 on a Windows 7 machine.

After having a look at the source it was trying to create a FileOutputStream from "NUL:" similar to the following piece of code

```
try {
            new FileOutputStream("NUL:").getChannel();
        } catch (FileNotFoundException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
```

The above gives a FileNotFound exception

When trying an echo in command prompt (following log) NULL only works

```
C:\Users\Admin>echo A > NUL:
The system cannot find the file specified.

C:\Users\Admin>
C:\Users\Admin>echo A > NULL:

C:\Users\Admin>
C:\Users\Admin>
```

When trying to executing the same "NUL:" on my Windows 8 laptop and given to a friend to execute it works.

When having a look at the registry the following also appears

http://technet.microsoft.com/library/Cc976138

It seems that it is a windows related issue? Does anyone know how to make "NUL:" work.

Regards,
Milinda

Comment: A windows file name can't have `:` in it. You are trying to call `getChannel()` on a File that *cannot* exist.

Comment: @TheLostMind It's not a file. In Windows, it's the null stream

Comment: @BackSlash- `new FileOutputStream("NUL:")` --> *Creates a file output stream to write to the file represented by the specified File/String object*

Comment: @TheLostMind As I said, `NUL:` is not a file. It's something like an environment variable pointing to a "fake" output stream in windows, so it works. Try this on a windows pc: `FileOutputStream out = new FileOutputStream("NUL:"); out.write(5); out.close();`. It will work. I'm on Windows 7, I don't think it will work on a linux machine.

Comment: @TheLostMind It is the null device, similar to /dev/null in Unix. It is a perfect bit sink, and a source of infinite ends of stream.

Comment: Apparently for some reason it does not work on my desktop and only "NULL" works however it does work on my laptop, any solutions

Comment: I suspect that NULL: is actually writing to a file named NULL; that's what happens on my (Windows 7) machine.  Did you try NUL rather than NUL: ?  I don't think the colon belongs, strictly speaking, though again, it works on my machine.

Comment: You can check whether the null device driver is running using `sc query Null`.

Comment: NULL: and NULL works in cmd when using echo however NUL and NUL: doesn't, NUL: is what is required, is there a way to set NUL: to point to NULL:. Also sc query Null shows that the state is running on the computer.